# RSpec - When should you use one assertion per spec?

Tags: rspec

As far as I can tell, the main benefit of adhering to the single assertion rule is that you get a fuller picture of the state of your test suite when you run it. Rather than failing and then not running subsequent assertions, you get to see exactly how many are failing.

That being said, the difference in performance between adhering to this rule and not adhering to it is significant. In terms of development time that really adds up over time, and it can also rack up costs on continuous integration platforms such as CircleCI.

If we look at this example of a test I wrote:

```
describe 'success' do
  before do
    result
  end

  it 'returns a user' do
    expect(result[0]).to eq(user)
  end

  it 'returns a success message' do
    expect(result[1]).to eq('Successfully registered')
  end

  it 'queries the user repository' do
    expect(user_repo).to have_received(:find_by).with(email: email)
  end

  it 'generates a hashed password' do
    expect(generate_hashed_password).to have_received(:call).with(password: password)
  end

  it 'creates the user in the database' do
    expect(user_repo).to have_received(:create).with(params[:user])
  end
end
```

And then at the same test written without the single assertion rule:

```
describe 'success' do
  before do
    result
  end

  it 'creates a user' do
    expect(result[0]).to eq(user)
    expect(result[1]).to eq('Successfully registered')
    expect(user_repo).to have_received(:find_by).with(email: email)
    expect(generate_hashed_password).to have_received(:call).with(password: password)
    expect(user_repo).to have_received(:create).with(params[:user])
  end
end
```

It seems to me that the rule is not worth sticking to in this scenario. Not only is the spec a lot more readable, it's around twice as performant, which has real beneficial consequences.

So my question is - when should you stick to the single assertion rule and when is it a better idea to break it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting from [betterspecs.org](http://www.betterspecs.org/)

> ..
> In isolated unit specs, you want each example to specify one (and only one) behavior. Multiple expectations in the same example are a signal that you may be specifying multiple behaviors.
> Anyway, in tests that are not isolated (e.g. ones that integrate with a DB, an external webservice, or end-to-end-tests), you take a massive performance hit to do the same setup over and over again, just to set a different expectation in each test. In these sorts of slower tests, I think it's fine to specify more than one isolated behavior.

So as 'rule' is supposed to be broken whenever pros are not as important as cons. I think is much more important to build your test carefully deciding what to test, and what not to, having always in mind the purpose of your test.
In the end, testing is just coding.
A good test should tell about your code, should give an insight about your intention to be flexible about the implementation of your public interface.

If to achieve this you have to put a couple of `expect` inside an `it` I would say go for it.